# CalDAV implementation

Tags: java, android, caldav

Currently, I research calDAV protocol on Android Java, I stuck in CalDAV Authentication. I understand clearly know how it works. Can everyone give me simple example project to demonstrate it? Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](http://www.androidadb.com/class/au/Authenticator.html) for CalDav authenticator usage:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    IBinder ret = null;
    if (ourAuthenticator == null) {
        ourAuthenticator = new Authenticator(this);
    }
    if (arg0.getAction().equals(AccountManager.ACTION_AUTHENTICATOR_INTENT)) {
        ret = ourAuthenticator.getIBinder();
    }
    return ret;
```